# Jersey POST method argument is null

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I have following REST service

```
@Stateless
@Path("/foo")
public class FooREST {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooREST.class);

    @EJB
    private FooService fooService;

    public FooREST() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return fooService.getFoos();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Foo> saveFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Calling the GET on `getFoos` returns list of foos as expected. However, when I POST list of foos, the `saveFoos` is injected with null argument. Weird enough, I don't see any kind of exception in the server logs. What may cause the null argument?

Answer (score 0):

ensure you are sending a json body like : [{Foo1},{Foo2}]